# Force Route::group(['domain'=>'external.com']) to return https-prefixed routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I created a new routes definition called `external.php`.

This is how it looks like:

```
Route::group([
    'domain' => 'example.org'
], function () {
    Route::post('oauth/token')->name('external.oauth.token');
```

This works fine, so `php artisan route:list` contains:

```
| example.org | POST     | oauth/token                | external.oauth.token            | Closure                                                 |                       |
```

If I do `route('external.oauth.token')` I am getting this result:

```
"http://example.org/oauth/token"
```

So my question is: How can I force the route to be secure/with https-prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force this group of routes to be secure:

```
Route::group(['domain' => ..., 'https'], function () {
    ...
});
```

Or for just that one route:

```
Route::post('oauth/token', ['uses' => ..., 'https'])->name('external.oauth.token');
```

---

For an actual external URL you could probably just add this URL to a config file and access it with a helper by name.

`config/urls.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'external' => [
        'oauth' => [
            'token' => 'https://example.org/oauth/token',
        ]
    ],
];
```

Helper method:

```
function urls($name)
{
    return config('urls.'. $name);
}
```

Where needed:

```
$url = urls('external.oauth.token');
```

You can name the method and the config and the keys as you wish, this was just an idea to match the name you used.

Comment: This works fine. One thing seems quite strange: If I use `route` in my controller, it automatically adds port `8000` to my request. I guess this is the case, because I am running the `php artisan serve` which delivers at `8000`. 

Is it possible to remove the port from `Route::group`?

Comment: the port is there because it isn't listening on the default port, you wouldn't be able to connect with out it

Comment: But the route points to an external service. I wanted to create route names for external API endpoints. And the API-Server does not listen on `https://...:8000`

Comment: routes aren't for external locations, they are for your applications routes

Comment: @SPQRInc I added a way to define some URLs and access them with a custom helper, if that helps